# How can I align this kind of paragraph on html

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I do this with the use of `css`.

[image]

This would be the tag:

```
<p>₱8500</p>
```

Comment: Ehm, you want a $ sign to come out looking like a ₱?

Comment: As @MrLister already asked: is this question about the alignment of the sign (you could wrap that in a span and position it as you want) or do you want to morph the "$" sign into a "₱" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use html `<sup></sup>` tags to get this effect.

```html
<sub>987</sub>abc<sup>123</sup>
```

Answer (score 2):

another approuch could be `::before` for `css` , keeps it inline.

```css
p::before {
  content: "₱";
  font-size: 11px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p>500</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<p> <sup>$</sup> 8500 </p>
```